# How can i stop wheel scrolling in ios datepicker

Tags: android, ios

I am dummy in android project. I made a little project about date picker.

I want to disable wheel scrolling for only day wheel. But when the user select past date, allow scrolling.If user select the future date, i want to disable wheel scrolling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635502/stop-circular-scrolling-of-date-picker

Comment: I tried this. But it did not work Log.i("last day",last+" lddd");
  if(last>calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
  {
   Log.i("greater","greater");
   day.scroll(1, curDay);} ..... If user future date , i want to set the day as current day in wheelview

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

Set the minimum date of the picker to NSDate.date()

Comment: T     I used this code code.google.com/p/android-wheel. I can not find this NSDate in code. Where i can stop scrolling.